# Web Crawler in Laravel

Tags: multithreading, laravel, queue, lumen

I have an android app that allows a user to search for something, the app breaks the sentence into words and crawls through a list of websites trying to find the page which has those particular words.  Now I am putting it as a job and queuing it which I assume may work for 1 user however I am concerned about when my app grows and I have 1000-50000 users all making searches at the same time, I obviously cannot use queues for that anymore.

What would be the best approach to doing this? I have done some research on multithreading in PHP but I would like some practical examples on this since I am not quite familiar with the concept.

Simply put, what I am asking for here is how to execute 1000-50000 jobs concurrently on laravel.  Please note that each job contains code that crawls through quite a few websites to search for data.

Comment: How many website in your list to search? And in each website you just crawl the home page or some pages inside?

Comment: 3-5 websites and I crawl up to 10 pages per site.

Answer (score 2):

I am not pretty sure if this the anwer that you are trying to get. This is just my opinion that I hope can give another approach to achieve your needs.

Having 1000-50000 concurent process is very big. It also will need more server resources. Let's say 1 user queue (for crawling each words, in each page in the websites) require 1MB of memory. Or may be 500kB.

```
500kB * 500000 = 250,000,000 KB = 243,190.66 MB = 236.57 GB
```

Quite big huh. IMO, instead of queueing based on user words query request. What you need is queueing for crawling the the site pages and save it to database/cache. In your case 3-5 websites with 10 pages per site. Lets say it 500 pages. Each user queue actually will do same crawling process right?

So crawling is done just once per page in each site (maybe once a day). At next user query request you don't need recrawl it, because it's already done. So user query result will just against the database that you already saved. I think, it will cut more process botteneck and also make search result will be faster.